# TFS setup advice

Tags: tfs

I am currently in the middle of a TFS 2010 multi-server installation and have the following questions:

- should i go with the default installation of having tfs sit on http://server:8080/tfs as i would probably prefer http://server/ or http://server:8080
- I can't seem to find the best practice for which user i should use to remotely connect to the reporting services - should this be a domain user, or a local machine account on the database server?
- If i install sharepoint and i want the database stored on another server, am i ok to install sharepoint as a single server or do i need to install "application only" and create a "farm"

that is all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> •should i go with the default
> installation of having tfs sit on
> http://server:8080/tfs as i would
> probably prefer http://server/ or
> http://server:8080

We have our hosted externaly so we go with a FQDN, but if not you should use the default as Visual Studio also uses this default. By all means setup a FQDN or other URL on port 80 to give people the choice, and to make the web access more accessable.

> •I can't seem to find the best
> practice for which user i should use
> to remotely connect to the reporting
> services - should this be a domain
> user, or a local machine account on
> the database server?

Network Service is fine and TFS will set everything up during the install. You can create a "domain\TfsReports" if it makes you feel better and I would recommend this if you are going to setup Kerberos or are runnign in a security consious enviroment.

> •If i install sharepoint and i want
> the database stored on another server,
> am i ok to install sharepoint as a
> single server or do i need to install
> "application only" and create a "farm"

You can put the Sharepoint databases anywher you like during the insatll. if you are doing what you sugest, remember not to lose them. A better option would be to integrate with your existing Sharepoint 2007/2010 corporate deployment.
[Integrate SharePoint 2010 with Team Foundation Server 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20120229114919/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/hinshelm/archive/2010/05/03/integrate-sharepoint-2010-with-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx)

Comment: As far as the authentication goes, when setting up on two servers TFS _doesn't_ set everthing up for you... this was the problem.

i setup a new account, gave it "login as a service" and gave this same user access to both Reporting services and SQL at the server level.

Comment: The instalation documentation is fairly explicit on what service accounts you need and what rights they need!